# Running two functions in parallel and passing the parameter returned by one function as argument to the other in python

Tags: python

I have implemented a sampler and a clock. I want to run the sampler and clock in parallel and at the same time I want the sampler to return it's end time to clock so that clock runs for that much time. These two functions are in some other module and it is being called from other module.

code for clock:

```
def clock_generator(self, freq, end_time):

    time_period = 1 / (freq)
    clock = 0
    while time.time<end_time:
        clock = 1
        time.sleep(((time_period) / 2))
        clock = 0
        time.sleep(((time_period) / 2))
```

code for sampler:

```
 def data_sample(self, path, result_file_name, time_index, formatted_data, time_period):

    start_time = time.time()

    """perform few operations"""

    end_time = time.time()
    return end_time
```

Comment: Did you mean to ask a question?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here? Are you trying to run the data sampler at a certain interval? Or do you want to start a clock when the data sampler is done?

Comment: @AzizSonawalla I want to run both data sampler and clock concurrently but I want the clock to run  only till the data sampler is running hence, I want to send the end time from data sampler to the clock.

Answer (score 0):

Following the clarification above "I want to run both data sampler and clock concurrently but I want the clock to run only till the data sampler is running hence, I want to send the end time from data sampler to the clock":

There's better ways to do this than running another process in parallel (depending on why you need the clock in a different function). Here's one way:

```
from time import time, sleep


class Clock:

  def __init__(self, freq):
    self.period = 1./freq

  def start(self):
    self.start = time()
    return self.start

  def getElapsed(self):
    return time() - self.start

  def getTick(self):
    elapsed = self.getElapsed();
    return int((elapsed/self.period) % 2)    # feel free to negate this condition

  def stop(self):
    self.end = time()
    return self.end


def data_sample():

    clock = Clock(5)
    print(clock.start())

    """perform few operations"""    # can call clock.getTick() here

    end = clock.stop()
    print(end)
    return end

data_sample()
```